# Receive gestures in a different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a main view controller that is able to process gestures in an iPad app.

I launch a second view controller via:

```
wVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc_webView"];
[self presentViewController:wVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If I now gesture while that VC is showing, the gestures are not processed. How can I "pass" the gestures to the first storyboard for subsequent processing so that I don't need to rewrite the whole gesture functionality in the new VC?

Answer (score 0):

OK so the answer is to use delegates.

For completion's sake, here is the way to do it:

Set up the first VC to be a delegate of the second, then in the second VC call the delegate function.

In original controller right before presenting the wVC:

```
wVC.delegate = self;
```

In the wVC.h file:

```
@protocol senddataProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)ProcessPasswordGesture:(NSInteger)iGest;
@end

@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;
```

In the wVC.m file:

```
@synthesize delegate;

[delegate ProcessPasswordGesture:<data>];
```

Hope this helps someone else!!